# How much funds or runway does the Monero foundation / marketing department have?

Tags: monero-foundation

How much funds does the Monero foundation or marketing department have to help promote Monero as of 2017-08?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Monero foundation or marketing department. If any funds are gathered, it's for a specific purpose via project-specific crowd-funding platform known as FFS (forum funding system): https://forum.getmonero.org/8/funding-required